# Is the following link structure valid?

Tags: url, parameters, google-analytics, tracking, key-value

I'm wondering whether the following structure of a link is valid:
So it should call a php script and pass a key-value-pair as arguments, but also carry the utm_campain tag along which is used by Google Analytics for tracking:

Example:
www.my-url.com/myScript.php?myKey=myValue&utm_campaign=myCampain

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to add the utm params along with your custom params in the URL. If you want to test it out manually before coding it up, take a look at this URL - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en